# How to generalize this mirror transformation to n dimensions?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, transformation

I have a set of points on the unit hypercube in *n* dimensions:

$$ \boldsymbol I_n = \{\boldsymbol x = (x_1, ... , x_n) : 0 \leq x_i \leq 1,\ i = 1, ...,n \} $$

The goal is to transform these points to the part of the hypercube where the coordinates of the points are in a non-descending order, which is the simplex defined as:

$$ \boldsymbol T_n = \{\boldsymbol x = (x_1, ... , x_n) : 0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq ... \leq x_n \leq 1 \} $$

I want to do this using the mirror transformation described in *"Section 2.3. Transformation Mirror"*, of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704001694) paper<sup>1</sup>.

The authors describe the transformation for $n=2$ and $n=3$ dimensions, and imply that it can be generalized for higher dimensions by stating that:

> This  transformation  is  fast,  even  for  high  dimensions.

However, they do not give a general method for $n$ dimensions, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it based on the 2 cases they present for 2 and 3 dimensions.

In case you can't access the article, here are the algorithms they give for 2 and 3 dimensions:

##### $ \boldsymbol{n = 2:} $

For the point $(x_1, x_2):$

$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{If} \quad x_1 \leq x_2 \quad& \textrm{then} \quad T(x_1, \,x_2) := (x_1, \, x_2), \\
&\textrm{else} \quad T(x_1, \, x_2) := (1 - x_1, \, 1 - x_2).
\end{align}
$$

##### $ \boldsymbol{n = 3:} $

For the point $(x_1, x_2, x_3):$

$$
\begin{align}
&\textrm{If}\quad x_3 \leq x_1 \quad\textrm{then}\quad (x_1,\, x_2,\, x_3) := 
(1-x_1, \, 1-x_2, \, 1-x_3),\\
&\textrm{If}\quad x_3 \leq x_2 \quad\textrm{then}\quad (x_1,\, x_2,\, x_3) := 
(x_1, \, 1-x_2+x_1, \, 1-x_3+x_1),\\
&\textrm{If}\quad x_2 \leq x_1 \quad\textrm{then}\quad (x_1,\, x_2,\, x_3) := 
(x_3-x_1, \, x_3-x_2, \, x_3)
\end{align}
$$

How would this look in $n$ dimensions?

1:
*Pillards, Tim; Cools, Ronald*, [**Transforming low-discrepancy sequences from a cube to a simplex**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2004.03.019), J. Comput. Appl. Math. 174, No. 1, 29-42 (2005). [ZBL1062.65006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1062.65006).

---

###### Update:


I think I have figured out part of the problem:

If we have the point $\boldsymbol{x}$, we essentially want to sort the coordinates in a non-descending order by performing these mirror operations described in the paper.

Lets say we have:
$$
\{\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1,...,x_i,...,x_j,...,x_n) : 0 \leq x_p \leq 1,\, p = 1,2,...,n\}
$$
and we compare the values of $x_i$ and $x_j$.

If they are not in the correct order (meaning $x_i > x_j$), then we perform the following mirror operation: 
Mirror all the coordinates of this point $\boldsymbol x$ which fall on the interval $(x_{i-1}, x_{j+1})$ over the midpoint $\frac{x_{i-1}+x_{j+1}}{2}$ of this inverval: 
$$\{x_k \in \boldsymbol x \,|\, x_{i-1} < x_k < x_{j+1}\}$$
$$x_k := x_{i-1} + x_{j+1} - x_k$$

If $i=1$ and/or $j=n$ then for this to work we will need to define $x_0$ and $x_{n+1}$, which are going to be the lower and upper bounds of the entire interval the coordinates are from:
$$x_0=0$$
$$x_{n+1}=1$$
Applying this to the cases shown in the paper: 
**$n=2:$** 
$$ x_0 = 0,\quad x_3 = 1$$
If $x_2 < x_1:$
$$ x_1 := x_0 + x_3 - x_1 = 1 - x_1 \\
x_2 := x_0 + x_3 - x_2 = 1 - x_2 $$

**$n=3:$** 
$$ x_0 = 0,\quad x_4 = 1$$
If $x_3 < x_1:$
$$ x_1 := x_0 + x_4 - x_1 = 1 - x_1 \\
x_2 := x_0 + x_4 - x_2 = 1 - x_2 \\
x_3 := x_0 + x_4 - x_3 = 1 - x_3 $$
If $x_3 < x_2:$
$$ x_1 := x_1 \\
x_2 := x_1 + x_4 - x_2 = x_1 + 1 - x_2 \\
x_3 := x_1 + x_4 - x_3 = x_1 + 1 - x_3 $$
If $x_2 < x_1:$
$$ x_1 := x_3 - x_1 \\
x_2 := x_3 - x_2 \\
x_3 := x_3 $$

Comment: This is obviously not a *linear* transformation.  Are you simply concerned with the definition, or perhaps with an efficient implementation of the mapping?

Comment: Having an implementation would be nice, but the definition would be enough.

Comment: Isn't the goal merely to sort coordinates into non-decreasing order...? If so, there's not a nice formula, but an $O(\log n)$ algorithm, and the right search terms are not about geometry, but list sorting.